# 1-1, onto from [0,1] to (0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Can you construct a 1-1, onto map from [0,1] to (0,1]?
I know there are similar questions being asked but I have not found any help or advice for this specific 1-1, onto map and am rather stuck. Thank you.

Comment: With Axiom of Choice, easily.

Comment: Several duplicates at hand...

Comment: @mniip It would be interresting to se how you actually use the AoC for this. It's just not to prove that there exists such a mapping (which we could do with the Schröder-Bernstein theorem).

Comment: @skyking I had an idea similar to Casper's, but instead of $2^{-n}$ I'd use $1/n$. Suppose $P(x, y) = (\exists n. x=1/n \land y=1/(n+1)) \lor((\not\exists n. x=1/n) \land x=y)$. AoC lets us turn the evident $\forall x. \exists y. P(x, y)$, into an actual function $\exists f. \forall x. P(x, f(x))$.

Comment: @mniip You definitely don't need AoC for that. You only need ASoS and to prove that $y$ is unique (in order to make the relation a function) which should be rather straight forward. If you resort to AoC you haven't actually constructed such a mapping, but only proved that such a mapping exists.

Comment: @skyking Indeed you are correct. I seem to have misinterpreted the usage of AoC in another construction similar to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map 0 to $\frac12$, map $\frac12$ to $\frac14$, map $\frac14$ to $\frac18$, etc., and map everything else to itself.